# Multithread program, that holds threads in vector instead of in an array

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've found a simple example, that shows, how to use `treads` in `C++`. I understand, how it works, nevertheless I'm not able to change the source to use `vector` of threads instead of an `array`. I want to use `vector` to be able to create as many threads I'd like to. Would anybody show me please, how to implement it and where do I make mistake (commented code is what I've tried to implement)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   // vector<pthread_t> vectorOfThreads;
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   int i;
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;

      // rc = pthread_create(&vectorOfThreads[i], NULL, 
      //                    PrintHello, (void *)i);

      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         return 1;
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the concrete problem you're facing? What did you try?

Comment: what is the error you are getting if you uncomment the vector version?

Comment: I think the problem is that the code uses the entry in `vectorOfThreads` that isn't there yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A default constructed vector (`vector<pthread_t> vectorOfThreads;`) starts off empty, which means that in your loop, accessing `vectorOfThreads[i]` leads to undefined behavior (probably a crash with a segfault).

If you create the vector as

```
vector<pthread_t> vectorOfThreads(NUM_THREADS);
```

it'll work.

Alternatively:

```
vector<pthread_t> vectorOfThreads;
//...
for(/*...*/) {
    pthread_t new_thread;
    rc = pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, 
                              PrintHello, (void *)i);
    vectorOfThread.push_back(new_thread);
}
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) on more details on what vectors and their member functions do.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to allocate the `pthread_t` element first :

```
pthread_t newThread;
rc = pthread_create(&newThread, NULL, PrintHello, (void *)i);
vectorOfThreads.push_back(newThread);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses the vector entry before it's been added to the vector. zakinster gives one solution. The other is to use :

```
  vectorOfThreads.resize(NUM_THREADS);
```

This will create a vector that has `NUM_THREADS` elements that are empty. You can now use these elements just like an array.